# How to unzip split files on OS X

Tags: macos, zip

How do I unzip a split zip file?

In Terminal, I wrote: `unzip filename.zip` and it did not unzip this file.

Terminal wrote:

```
$ unzip filename.zip
Archive:  filename.zip
warning [filename.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
  attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
  together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
  doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  4
file #2:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  98
file #3:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  471
file #4:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  6635222
```

Double clicking of this file creating `filename.zip.cpgz`

What can I do?

Comment: So, are there any other parts of this file or do you only have this one part? If you only have one, are you trying to get the contents of this part only?

Comment: Have you tried other uncompression tools? I'd run uncompress and gunzip on the file and see if was processed with one of those.

Comment: It's no problem to unzip multiple archive using unarchiver.app but I'm looking for the terminal command to do this without of using any apps.

Comment: First I'd take it over to a Windows box and try 7Zip on it.  If that doesn't work I'd try to find the rest of the zip file pieces and concatenate them together.

Answer (score 74):

This was the straight forward and only solution that worked for me on OS X (taken from [here](http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2012/12/mac-os-x-createextract-split-zip.html)).

**1. To create a split zip archive** (a series of files named zip, z01, z02...), run following command in Terminal:

```
zip -s 100m -x "*.DS_Store" -r split-foo.zip foo/
```

**2. To extract a split zip archive** (a series of files named zip, z01, z02...), run following command in Terminal:

First, combine the split archive to a single archive:

```
zip -s 0 split-foo.zip --out unsplit-foo.zip
```

Extract the single archive using unzip:

```
unzip unsplit-foo.zip
```

Comment: if you have splitted binaries, like file.zip.001, file.zip.002 ... you may just need to combine the files e.g. using `cat` command: `cat file.zip.* > single.zip`

Comment: @abimelex your comment helped solve my exact scenario!

Comment: You're the man @abimelex !!!!! - I did have to use [p7zip](https://superuser.com/a/667076) to extract them because of this error: `need PK compat. v5.1 (can do v4.5)`

Comment: I'm glad to help. Since the comment has a lot of up-votes I added it as answer too.

Comment: `zip -s 0 split-foo.zip --out unsplit-foo.zip` doesn't make any sense as a split archive? How would you combine two files into one zip file?

Answer (score 16):

Just `cat` all zip files in sequence to a single file and use `unzip` command on that.

For example:

```
cat file.zip.001 > s.zip 
cat file.zip.002 >> s.zip
cat file.zip.003 >> s.zip

unzip s.zip
```

Comment: didn't work for me as I got this error message ````warning [s.zip]:  1629602286 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile````

Comment: @gota If that happens, use the top-rated answer: https://superuser.com/a/517758/565974

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 16):

additionally to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/517758) if you have split binaries, like `file.zip.001`, `file.zip.002` ... you may just need to combine the files e.g. using cat command:

```
cat file.zip.* > single.zip
```

Comment: didn't work for me as I got this error message warning ````[s.zip]: 1629602286 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile````

Comment: Try to verify the order using `echo file.zip.*`.

Answer (score 14):

I hit this issue when trying to re-assemble a large directory downloaded from Google Drive.

Similar to [this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1255221/how-to-unzip-multiple-zip-files-into-a-single-directory-structure-e-g-google-d), if you are dealing with a set of zip files that do not include numbered file extensions (foo.z01, foo.z02, etc) and are simply multiple zip files that should be unarchived together into the same directory, the following worked for me:

```
unzip '*.zip' -d /path/to/unzip/destination
```

Comment: You are my saviour  This is exactly my case.

Comment: this is the only answer here that worked for me for the use case of downloaded files from Google Drive.

Comment: This should be accepted answer!

Answer (score 4):

Tested on a 10.8.5 Mac OS

- Use Stuffit Expander free version
- Just drag the last file (the one with .ZIP extension) in Stuffit
- Wait for a while because it seeme Stuffit re-build first the complete file
- See all your files unzipped

Comment: best and cleanest answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just run this command on the bash prompt to concatenate the zips.

```
for i in `seq 1 5`; do cat file.zip.0$i>>uncut-version.zip; done
```

the above example has 5 parts.

Then unzip the file using your favourite method

```
unzip uncut-version.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, within OS X 10.11.6, i had a multipart archive with extensions

```
.z01
.z02
... (etc)
.zip
```

Using

```
zip -s 0 in.zip --out out.zip
```

did get me a single zip. It did not extract with unzip, but did with 7zip, installed via MacPorts:

```
port install p7zip
7za x out.zip
```

Comment: 7-zip worked for me on the original files. No need to zip first...

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is very simple: Open the .z01 file with the free Mac application The Unarchiver (available from the Mac App Store). It handles the extraction nicely.

Answer (score 2):

This was the most simple solution I could find:

```
find ./ -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Unzip all files using terminal
unzip filename001.zip, filename002.zip
that will automatically add files in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/). I had several files with extensions like .z01, .z02, .z03 and zip.
I just extracted main zip with Keka and it did it's job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

in MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra, working way is to:

`cat filename.z01, filename.z02, filename.z03 filename.zip > unsplited_foo.zip`

and after that use `unzip`:

`unzip unsplited_foo.zip`

NOTE: be careful order of files in `cat` is matter