# How can I install 7zip so I can run it from Terminal on OS X

Tags: macos, 7-zip, terminal.app

I would like to be able to run 7zip from the command line on Mac.   Does anyone have instructions on how to set this up?

Answer (score 444, accepted):

To install [p7zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/) using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), first update your `brew` formulae to be sure you are getting the latest `p7zip`.

```
$ brew update
```

Use Homebrew to install `p7zip`:

```
$ brew install p7zip
```

Add all files in the `sputnik` directory to the compressed file `heed.7z`:

```
$ 7z a heed.7z sputnik
```

Unzip `heed.7z`:

```
$ 7z x heed.7z
```

Comment: same for macports:
`sudo port install p7zip` no problem

Comment: @AlanBlount thanks for adding instructions for MacPorts.

Comment: On a tangent, my brew update required sudo, is that ok or not? How can I change its behavior in this case to run without sudo?

Comment: @pal4life Check the permissions on your [Cellar directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800527/homebrew-install-permissions-issue).

Comment: What is sputnik? and what is heed?

Comment: @MaciekSemik Example file names.

Comment: @MaciekSemik https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-OCjvbV2Z4

Comment: I had to come here to find out that the command isn't p7zip, it is 7z...

Comment: i would have a better chance of destroying the entire universe by accident than stumbling upon the correct syntax

Comment: @MikeP I didn't even realize until I read your comment...!

Comment: Now I only need to figure out how to extract to a sub-folder...

Answer (score 44):

On the [download page of 7-zip](http://7-zip.org/download.html), there are several options for OS X. Unfortunately, they seem to be with a GUI, or not available at the moment.

---

You can download p7zip though.

> p7zip is the command line version of 7-Zip for Unix/Linux, made by an independent developer

It is distributed as Linux binaries and in source code form [on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/p7zip/).

Download the source code, and run `make` in the folder you extract the archive to. It will automatically build `7za` for your OS. You might need Xcode and its command line tools for this to work.

```
$ cd Downloads/p7zip_9.20.1
$ make
[...]
$ cd bin
$ ls
7za
$ ./7za 

7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=de_DE.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Usage: 7za <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
       [<@listfiles...>]

<Commands>
  a: Add files to archive
  b: Benchmark
  d: Delete files from archive
  e: Extract files from archive (without using directory names)
  l: List contents of archive
  t: Test integrity of archive
  u: Update files to archive
  x: eXtract files with full paths
<Switches>
  -ai[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: Include archives
  -ax[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: eXclude archives
  -bd: Disable percentage indicator
  -i[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: Include filenames
  -m{Parameters}: set compression Method
  -o{Directory}: set Output directory
  -p{Password}: set Password
  -r[-|0]: Recurse subdirectories
  -scs{UTF-8 | WIN | DOS}: set charset for list files
  -sfx[{name}]: Create SFX archive
  -si[{name}]: read data from stdin
  -slt: show technical information for l (List) command
  -so: write data to stdout
  -ssc[-]: set sensitive case mode
  -t{Type}: Set type of archive
  -u[-][p#][q#][r#][x#][y#][z#][!newArchiveName]: Update options
  -v{Size}[b|k|m|g]: Create volumes
  -w[{path}]: assign Work directory. Empty path means a temporary directory
  -x[r[-|0]]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: eXclude filenames
  -y: assume Yes on all queries

$ ./7za a 7za.7z 7za 

7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=de_DE.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)
Scanning

Creating archive 7za.7z

Compressing  7za      

Everything is Ok

$ ls
7za    7za.7z
```

Comment: Before "make" I had to issue command "cp makefile.macosx_64bits makefile.machine"

Answer (score 19):

If you only need to extract archives, [unar](http://unarchiver.c3.cx/commandline) (a command line version of The Unarchiver) also supports 7zip.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to The Unarchiver. The GUI version works great on Mac too.

Answer (score 7):

`p7zip` is not maintained anymore. It's been at 17.xx for years. 7zip is at 23.xx. It's missing important features like utilizing all CPU cores (7zip 17.xx is single core)

`brew install sevenzip` will install the package still maintained by the original developers (https://7-zip.org).

To use, `7zz --help`