# How to unzip multiple zip files into a single directory structure (e.g. Google Drive folder export)

Tags: linux, command-line, zip

Assume you started with an uncompressed directory `A`, with the following structure:

```
$ tree A
A
└── inner_dir
    ├── file1.txt
    └── file2.txt

1 directory, 2 files
```

Now assume you've been given two zip files `1.zip` and `2.zip` derived from `A`.  `1.zip` contains only `file1.txt`, and `2.zip` contains only `file2.txt`:

```
# -l flag simply lists file contents

$ unzip -l 1.zip 
Archive:  1.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-09-30 21:49   A/
        0  2017-09-30 22:27   A/inner_dir/
        0  2017-09-30 21:49   A/inner_dir/file1.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     3 files

$ unzip -l 2.zip 
Archive:  2.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-09-30 21:49   A/
        0  2017-09-30 22:27   A/inner_dir/
        0  2017-09-30 22:27   A/inner_dir/file2.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     3 files
```

What command can I use to programmatically reconstitute the original unzipped directory `A` from the combination of `1.zip` and `2.zip`?

**Context:** when exporting a large directory from Google Drive, the contents are split across a set of 2 or more zip files.  Each zip file contains some subset of the files, which when taken collectively, reconstitute the original directory.  Which files are contains in which zip appears to be more or less random.  I'm looking for a solution which generalizes to n > 1 zip files, not just the special case of exactly 2 files.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Move the set of files you want to unzip to a dedicated directory, and then use `unzip`:

```
$ unzip '*.zip' -d combined

Archive:  1.zip
   creating: combined/A/
   creating: combined/A/inner_dir/
 extracting: combined/A/inner_dir/file1.txt  

Archive:  2.zip
 extracting: combined/A/inner_dir/file2.txt  

2 archives were successfully processed.
```

Check:

```
$ tree combined
combined
└── A
    └── inner_dir
        ├── file1.txt
        └── file2.txt

2 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: I struggled a lot before finding this "obvious" solution. It's obvious because once `unzip` creates a folder, it doesn't recreate it when extracting the next archive. Doing so, the extraction is incremental. Thank you

Comment: Skips files with accented characters in file name. Any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

@lcharbon your problem is with the way zip handles non-standard encoding.

You can solve it by using p7zip, that handles that better.

Here's the analog command using p7zip:

`7z x '*.zip' -ocombined`

You can install p7zip on mac using brew `brew install p7zip` or your distro's package managers on linux.

Comment: Hi Pedro  you have made a claim about zip, you should provide a reference for it do yhat others csn tell it is true.